# Accessing subclass functions of member of collection of parent class objects

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, inheritance

(Refer Update #1 for a concise version of the question.)

We have an (abstract) class named `Games` that has subclasses, say `BasketBall` and `Hockey` (and probably many more to come later).

Another class `GameSchedule`, must contain a collection `GamesCollection` of various `Games` objects. The issue is that we would, at times, like to iterate  only through the `BasketBall` objects of `GamesCollection` and call functions that are specific to it (and not mentioned in the `Games` class).

That is, `GameSchedule` deals with a number of objects that broadly belong to `Games` class, in the sense that they *do* have common functions that are being accessed; at the same time, there is  more granularity at which they are to be handled.

We would like to come up with a design that avoids unsafe downcasting, and is extensible in the sense that creating many subclasses under `Games` or any of its existing subclasses must not necessitate the addition of too much code to handle this requirement.

Examples:

- A clumsy solution that I came up with, that doesn't do *any* downcasting at all, is to have dummy functions in the `Game` class for every subclass specific function that has to be called from `GameSchedule`. These dummy functions will have an overriding implementation in the appropriate subclasses which actually require its implementation.
- We could explicitly maintain different containers for various subclasses of `Games` instead of a single container. But this would require a lot of extra code in `GameSchedule`, when the number of subclasses grow. Especially if we need to iterate through all the `Games` objects.

Is there a neat way of doing this?

Note: the code is written in C++

Update# 1: I realized that the question can be put in a much simpler way. Is it possible to have a container class for any object belonging to a hierarchy of classes? Moreover, this container class must have the ability to pick elements belonging to (or derive from) a particular class from the hierarchy and return an appropriate list.

In the context of the above problem, the container class must have functions like `GetCricketGames`, `GetTestCricketGames`, `GetBaseballGame` etc.,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly one of the problems that The ["Tell, Don't Ask"](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask) principle was created for.

You're describing an object that holds onto references to other objects, and wants to ask them what type of object they are before telling them what they need to do. From the article linked above:

> *The problem is that, as the caller, you should not be making decisions based on the state of the called object that result in you then changing the state of the object. The logic you are implementing is probably the called object’s responsibility, not yours. For you to make decisions outside the object violates its encapsulation.*

If you break the rules of [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29), you not only introduce the runtime risks incurred by rampant downcasts, but also make your system significantly less maintainable by making it easier for components to become tightly coupled.

---

Now that that's out there, let's look at how the "Tell, Don't Ask" could be applied to your design problem.

Let's go through your stated constraints (in no particular order):

1. `GameSchedule` needs to iterate over all games, performing general operations
2. `GameSchedule` needs to iterate over a subset of all games (e.g., `Basketball`), to perform type-specific operations
3. No downcasts
4. Must easily accommodate new `Game` subclasses

The first step to following the "Tell, Don't Ask" principle is identifying the actions that will take place in the system. This lets us take a step back and evaluate **what** the system should be doing, without getting bogged down into the details of **how** it should be doing it.

You made the following comment in @MarkB's answer:

> If there's a `TestCricket` class inheriting from `Cricket`, and it has many specific attributes concerning the timings of the various innings of the match, and we would like to initialize the values of all `TestCricket` objects' timing attributes to some preset value, I need a loop that picks all `TestCricket` objects and calls some function like `setInningTimings(int inning_index, Time_Object t)`

In this case, the action is: *"Initialize the inning timings of all `TestCricket` games to a preset value."*

This is problematic, because the code that wants to perform this initialization is unable to differentiate between `TestCricket` games, and other games (e.g., `Basketball`). But maybe it doesn't need to...

Most games have some element of time: Basketball games have time-limited periods, while Baseball games have (basically) innings with basically unlimited time. Each type of game could have its own completely unique configuration. This is not something we want to offload onto [a single class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object).

Instead of asking each game what type of `Game` it is, and then telling it *how* to initialize, consider how things would work if the `GameSchedule` simply told each `Game` object to initialize. This delegates the responsibility of the initialization to the subclass of `Game` - the class with *literally* the most knowledge of what type of game it is.

This can feel really weird at first, because the `GameSchedule` object is relinquishing control to another object. This is an example of the [Hollywood Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_Principle). It's a completely different way of solving problems than the approach most developers initially learn.

This approach deals with the constraints in the following ways:

1. `GameSchedule` can iterate over a list of `Game`s without any problem
2. `GameSchedule` no longer needs to know the subtypes of its `Game`s
3. No downcasting is necessary, because the subclasses themselves are handling the subclass-specific logic
4. When a new subclass is added, no logic needs to be changed anywhere - the subclass itself implements the necessary details (e.g., an `InitializeTiming()` method).

---

**Edit:** Here's an example, as a proof-of-concept.

```
struct Game
{
    std::string m_name;

    Game(std::string name)
        : m_name(name)
    {
    }

    virtual void Start() = 0;
    virtual void InitializeTiming() = 0;
};

// A class to demonstrate a collaborating object
struct PeriodLengthProvider
{
    int GetPeriodLength();
}

struct Basketball : Game
{
    int m_period_length;
    PeriodLengthProvider* m_period_length_provider;

    Basketball(PeriodLengthProvider* period_length_provider)
        : Game("Basketball")
        , m_period_length_provider(period_length_provider)
    {
    }

    void Start() override;

    void InitializeTiming() override
    {
        m_period_length = m_time_provider->GetPeriodLength();
    }
};

struct Baseball : Game
{
    int m_number_of_innings;

    Baseball() : Game("Baseball") { }

    void Start() override;

    void InitializeTiming() override
    {
        m_number_of_innings = 9;
    }
}


struct GameSchedule
{
    std::vector<Game*> m_games;

    GameSchedule(std::vector<Game*> games)
        : m_games(games)
    {
    }

    void StartGames()
    {
        for(auto& game : m_games)
        {
           game->InitializeTiming();
           game->Start();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: That gives me a lot of insight. But some points are unclear to me. What if `Gameschedule` has to inform the `TestCricket` class, what value it has to set? And what if the type of this value is unknown to `Game`? For example, what if the argument that has to be passed is an object like `TestCricketTimings` which `Game` doesn't understand, but the classes `TestCricketTimings` and `GameSchedule` can only understand? I hope I'm not confusing.

Comment: Actually, let's just relax things a little bit and forget the second point I just stated about the type not being known. If you could solve the problem of how `GameSchedule` can pass information to the members of the container through the idea you have portrayed it'll be great!  
If I understood you right, your solution sounds similar to my second solution. What if there is some function that just *can't* be put in the `Game` class for everyone to implement?  Here, `InitializeTiming` makes sense. But, there could be very specific functions that I wouldn't want to push up to the parent class.

Comment: Excellent questions. Remember, `GameSchedule` has relinquished control. It is no longer passing information to the games; rather the games are responsible for retrieving he information they need. (Kind of like moving from a [push-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) model to a [pull-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_technology) one). However that information made its way into the `GameSchedule`, it instead makes its way into the `Game` subclass (e.g., via [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)).

Comment: As for functionality that can't be generalized to all games, there's definitely no reason to shoehorn it in. Instead, consider if such requests *should* be getting routed through the `GameSchedule`, or if they would be better suited for a *different* object. (With this approach, you'll see a much thinner `GameSchedule` class than you may have originally pictured).

Comment: Could you shed some light on the implementation? (Just a teeny-weeny example would do...) The motivation behind the idea seems clear, but I'm confused about how you've picturized it!

Comment: I've edited my answer to include some sample code. It's pretty contrived, but hopefully still helps fill in some of the gaps.

Comment: I've been able to decouple my problem from the issue of sending parameters etc., I just realized that my question essentially boils down to having a container that can handle a hierarchy of objects and must be able to return the set of objects that belong under any particular class in the hierarchy. For example, the `GameContainer` must be have a function `GetCricketGames`, `GetTestCricketGames`, `GetBaseballGames` and must return appropriate lists of objects. Does this give new ideas?

Comment: Yes, the game container can be composed of individual containers; one for each type of game. If it also needs to support a `GetAllGames` method, then you just need to define a custom iterator that traverses each of the subcontainers.

Comment: Aha. There's a catch there! When I want `GetCricketGame` it must iterate through *all* the containers for every subclass of `Cricket`! How would you keep track of such things?

Comment: The first thing we should ask is "do we *need* to keep track of such things?" That is, when you call `GetCricketGame`, and get all instances of `Cricket` (and its subclasses), what are you going to do with them? It *might* be something that can be delegated to the instances themselves. The point in all this is to question your design; to think of different ways you could tackle the problem at hand. This site describes this mindset really well: http://programmingwithoutifs.blogspot.com/2009/02/challenge-one-bergin-swing-calculator.html?m=1

Answer (score 1):

You've already identified the first two options that came to my mind: Make the base class have the methods in question, or maintain separate containers for each game type.

The fact that you don't feel these are appropriate leads me to believe that the "abstract" interface you provide in the `Game` base class may be far too concrete. I suspect that what you need to do is step back and look at the base interface.

You haven't given any concrete example to help, so I'm going to make one up. Let's say your basketball class has a `NextQuarter` method and hockey has `NextPeriod`. Instead, add to the base class a `NextGameSegment` method, or something that abstracts away the game-specific details. *All* the game-specific implementation details should be hidden in the child class with only a game-general interface needed by the schedule class.

Comment: Let me make it clearer: In essence, the `GameSchedule` class must be able to access *all* the functions of any `Game` object.  There are some common functions that are present, which might be invoked for *every* object. At the same time, there are some functions that are NOT common, that have to be invoked for the appropriate objects.

Comment: As to why I don't want separate containers: let's say the class hierarchy growing from `Games` becomes huge and I have many subclasses of subclasses. I would have to have a container corresponding to EVERY class that inherits from `Games`. That seems to be an exponentially clumsy solution to me.

Comment: @Enigman Can you elaborate with a specific example about *why* `GameSchedule` needs to be able to access *all* arbitrary functions of *all* child classes? This might help provide you a C++-solution.

Comment: If there's a `TestCricket` class inheriting from `Cricket`, and it has many  specific attributes concerning the timings of the various innings of the match, and we would like to initialize the values of all `TestCricket` objects' timing attributes to some preset value, I need a loop that picks all `TestCricket` objects and calls some function like `setInningTimings(int inning_index, Time_Object t)`

Answer (score 0):

C# supports reflections and by using the "is" keyword or GetType() member function you could do these easily. If you are writing your code in unmanaged C++, I think the best way to do this is add a GetType() method in your base class (Games?). Which in its turn would return an enum, containing all the classes that derive from it (so you would have to create an enum too) for that. That way you can safely determine the type you are dealing with only through the base type. Below is an example:

```
enum class GameTypes { Game, Basketball, Football, Hockey };

class Game
{
public:
    virtual GameTypes GetType() { return GameTypes::Game; }
}

class BasketBall : public Game
{
public:
    GameTypes GetType() { return GameTypes::Basketball; }
}
```

and you do this for the remaining games (e.g. Football, Hockey). Then you keep a container of Game objects only. As you get the Game object, you call its GetType() method and effectively determine its type.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to have it all, and you can't do that. :) Either you need to do a downcast, or you'll need to utilize something like the visitor pattern that would then require you to do work every time you create a new implementation of Game. Or you can fundamentally redesign things to eliminate the need to pick the individual Basketballs out of a collection of Games.

And FWIW: downcasting may be ugly, but it's not unsafe as long as you use pointers and check for null:

```
for(Game* game : allGames)
{
    Basketball* bball = dynamic_cast<Basketball*>(game);
    if(bball != nullptr)
        bball->SetupCourt();
}
```

Comment: I understand that I'm trying to have it all, but wait. I don't mind doing "work". Just that I would like to know if there's a neater way out that avoids downcasting. As for Visitor pattern, don't I have to create a visitor for *every* operation? I have many tiny operations that have to be done that might eventually be used by just two subclasses in the hierarchy of `Games`.

Comment: Yes, unless it's possible to bundle a bunch of those operations together into one, you'd need a separate visitor implementation for each operation. And each visitor would need to have a separate Visit() overload for each concrete Game type (or at least each one that needs to be visited).

I run into problems like this from time to time, and have always wound up either redesigning or holding my nose and doing the downcast (or adding a visitor). So I'll be thrilled if anyone else has a better idea. :)

Comment: I'm really intrigued by this problem that I've come across. I suspected that this will be quite a common issue but was surprised to see a  lack of sources on the internet that actually addressed that. I still think a better solution might exist. I'm yet to understand the `enum' solution posted in one of the answers here. Do check that out!

Comment: The enum idea would let you determine whether you were dealing with a Basketball without doing a cast, but you'd still need to do a cast before you could call any Basketball-specific functions on it.

Comment: I've updated the question with an equivalent, simpler version of the problem. Does that help?

Comment: In response to your Update #1; yes, something like that is certainly *possible* (though it would likely require downcasting inside the container, which puts us right back where we were); whether it's a good idea is a different question. Something along the lines of Lilshieste's answer is the ideal solution, but that is naturally the approach that requires the most work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the strategy pattern here.

Each game type has its own scheduling strategy which derives from the common strategy used by your game schedule class and decouples the dependency between the specific game and game schedule.